# How can I solve this java programming challenge involving queues with the minimum memory requirement?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, queue

So I have this programming challenge http://www.codewars.com/kata/double-cola where I have a list of persons in a queue and each time a person arrives to the first position it gets doubled and goes to the end of the queue.

For example I have x,y,z

x,y,z next loop is
y,z,x,x then z,x,x,y,y then x,x,y,y,z,z then x,y,y,z,z,x,x then y,y,z,z,x,x,x,x etc

This is my code that runs perfectly in eclipse.

```
public class Line {

static Node first;
    static Node last;
    static int N;

    private static class Node
    {
        String name;
        Node next;
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty() { return first == null; }

    public static void enqueue(String name)
    {
        Node oldlast = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.name = name;
        last.next = oldlast;
        if(isEmpty()) first = last;
        else oldlast.next = last;
        N++;
    }

    public static String dequeue()
    {
        String name = first.name;
        first = first.next;
        N--;
        if(isEmpty()) last = null;
        return name;
    }

    public static String WhoIsNext(String[] names, int n)
    {
        // Your code is here...

        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) enqueue(names[i]);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            String name = dequeue();
            enqueue(name);
            enqueue(name);
        }

        return last.name;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I run it, the program starts well, giving the correct answers but around the 12 test it starts to give me a wrong answer. For example given an n = 3667 to the method WhoIsNext my answer in eclipse that has the same code is = Penny that is the correct answer, but in the coding web page it gives me = Leonard so my hipothesis is that memory is starting to end so the program starts giving wrong answers after the 12/13 test. How can I improve my code in order to pass all tests?

this are the tests.

```
public class ListTests {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 1;  
      assertEquals("Sheldon", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
      @Test
    public void test2() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 6;  
      assertEquals("Sheldon", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
      @Test
    public void test3() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 1802;  
      assertEquals("Penny", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
      @Test
    public void test4() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n =  2;  
      assertEquals("Leonard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
     @Test
    public void test6() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 10;  
      assertEquals("Penny", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
     @Test
    public void test7() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 534;  
      assertEquals("Rajesh", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
     @Test
    public void test8() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 5033;  
      assertEquals("Howard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
    @Test
    public void test9() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 10010;  
      assertEquals("Howard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
     @Test
    public void test10() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 63;  
      assertEquals("Rajesh", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
     @Test
    public void test11() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 841;  
      assertEquals("Leonard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
     @Test
    public void test12() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 3667;  
      assertEquals("Penny", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
     @Test
    public void test13() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 38614;  
      assertEquals("Howard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
    @Test
    public void test14() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 1745;  
      assertEquals("Leonard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
   @Test
    public void test15() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 8302;  
      assertEquals("Rajesh", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
    @Test
    public void test16() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 12079;  
      assertEquals("Sheldon", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
    @Test
    public void test17() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 28643950;  
      assertEquals("Leonard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
    @Test
    public void test18() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 159222638;  
      assertEquals("Howard", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
   @Test
    public void test19() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 121580142;  
      assertEquals("Penny", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
   @Test
    public void test20() {
      String[] names = new String[] { "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" };
      int n = 1000000000;  
      assertEquals("Penny", new Line().WhoIsNext(names, n));
    }
}
```

Comment: @FallAndLearn lets assume we have x y z as 3 persons in a queue , n would be the number of dequeue's we need to do or number of movings in the queue so if n is 0 it stays the same x y z, when n is 1 is now y z x x then if n is 2 then now is z x x y y if its 3 then x x y y z z and so on. We need to return the name of the last person in the queue given a n. So again if they give us n =2 we would have the queue like this z x x y y so we return the name of y because is the last item in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not create so many String object in the queue.

You can use a integer queue, with the value of the index of persons' array.

**Edit:**

After seen the question from the url, I think you need not move the person really.

1. Split the problem to little steps, which deals with every person.
2. The number of each person in the queue, increases by twice after each step.
3. The last step can not deal with all persons, so count the index of the person.

Here is the code, which can be accepted:

```
public class Line {
    public static String WhoIsNext(String[] names, int n)
    {
        // Your code is here...
        final int personNum = names.length;
        int loop = 1;
        int curPersonQueueNum = personNum * loop;
        while (n > curPersonQueueNum){
            n -= curPersonQueueNum;
            loop*=2;
            curPersonQueueNum = personNum * loop;
        }
        n = (int) Math.ceil((double)n / loop);
        return names[n - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a straightforward algorithm to solve this. As you can see at test20, it's too expensive to solve the problem when n=1000000000.

You can solve this with pure math. For example, separate x,y,z to groups like (xyz) (xxyyzz) (xxxyyyzzz) and reduce the number of each group to get the specific group, then mod n (according the which group you found) to find out which output should be.